# Ajax não roda no Chrome e IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, front-end

O código abaixo não roda no IE e Chrome, acusa erro no `xhttp.send()`, mas no Mozilla funciona. O que acontece?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "teste.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Mensagem de erro:

> ajax.html:20 Failed to load file:///D:/Desktop/estudandoJs/ajax/teste.txt: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https

Comment: Consegue nos dizer qual é a mensagem completa do erro?

Comment: ajax.html:20 Failed to load file:///D:/Desktop/estudandoJs/ajax/teste.txt: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: A mensagem diz o que está errado: a URL requisitada deve estar em um destes protocolos citados, não com `file://`. Com certeza é duplicata no site, então aconselho a utilizar a busca. Se eu achar, colocarei aqui.